# What is the covariant represantation of $\hat{y}$ in cylinder coordinates?

Tags: tensors

I know the formula for changing systems however i keep getting the wrong result and i can understand why. Here is my calculation:
$A=\hat{y}$
$A_{i}=\left(0,1,0\right)\ \ \ $
$\bar{A}_{j}=\frac{dq^{i}}{d\bar{q}^{j}}A_{i}ּ\ \ \ $
$\bar{A}_{j}=\frac{dq^{2}}{d\bar{q}^{j}}\ \ \ A_{2}=\frac{dq^{2}}{d\bar{q}^{j}}=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\rho},\frac{\partial y}{\partial\varphi},\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)=\sin\left(\varphi\right)\hat{\rho}+\cos\left(\varphi\right)\rho\hat{\rho}$

this solution is wrong, Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is your expression for $y$ in terms of $\rho,\ \varphi,\ z$?

Comment: $y=\rho\sin\left(\varphi\right)$

Comment: Please show more steps in your calculations. Does the triplet $\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\rho},\frac{\partial y}{\partial\varphi},\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)$ contain the coefficients of $\hat\rho,\ \hat\varphi,\ \hat z$ respectively? You seem to mix vectors and real values: isn't $A_2$ a real value, not a vector?